# AutoModelSelect2Field not working using django-select2

Tags: django, jquery-select2

I am using select2 for my dropdowns. I have dropdown that has some 18000 entries , so I want to use HeavySelect2Widget for it. I getting an error 
           
 **Reverse of 'django_select2_central_json' with arguments () and keyword arguments '{}' not found**
Any idea what's the problem.The class and field name used is given below

---

```
class EmployeeChoices(AutoModelSelect2Field):
   fname = FirstName()
   queryset = [(1,'value 1')]#fname.getAllNames()
   search_fields = ['name__icontains',]
```

---

```
field_name = EmployeeChoices(
    required=False,
    widget=AutoHeavySelect2Widget(
        select2_options={
            'placeholder': u"Select a choice"
        }
    ),
    label=''
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to include the django_select2 urls in your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(...),
    url(r'^someurlprefix/', include('django_select2.urls')),
    url(...),
)
```

`r'^someprefix/'` is a regex expression, and the url_patterns uses this regex expression to map urls to view functions. If you specify the prefix here (it can even be `r''`, that's what I personally use), Django's `reverse` function will automatically provide the right url to get to the `django_select2_central_json` view.

Also check out the documentation on Django's [url dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/).

Comment: Added it .. still got the error .. can you tell me about the r'^someurlprefix/' part .. what prefix to use and where to specify it . Thanks

Comment: @WaheedKhan Updated my answer, I hope it is clear what I mean now.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to add the following line in the directory: /static/suit/js/suit.js

Add:

```
(function ($) {
    Suit.after_inline.register('init_select2', function(inline_prefix, row){
        $(row).find('select').select2(); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

add django_select2 urls in your Project setting urls.py:

`url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),`